# Dane Davis, partial filmography available on Netflix

Tags: sound-design

Here is the entire list of easy access movies by Dane A. Davis.All are instant films on Netflix.

1.Crips and bloods: Made in America (2008)          co-supervising sound editor, Sound designer

2.Battle in Seattle (2007)                            Sound effects editor

3.The good night (2007)                           Supervising sound designer

4.Aeon Flux (2005)                       Supervising sound designer, Supervising sound 
editor

5.The Lost city  (2005)                            Sound designer

6.The Matrix Revolutions (2003)                      Sound designer,Supervising sound editor

7.The Matrix Reloaded (2003)                          Sound designer, Supervising sound editor

8.Ghost Ship (2002)                                   Supervising sound editor

9.Dogtown and Z-Boys (2001/02)                                Supervising sound editor

10.Sand  (2000)                              Sound designer, sound re-recording mixer, Supervising sound editor

11.House on Haunted Hill (1999)                               Sound designer, Supervising sound editor

12.Go (1999)                                                                          Supervising sound editor

13.Phoenix (1998)                                                               Supervising sound editor

14.Panther (1995)                                                                Supervising sound editor

15.Phantom 3 Lord of the Dead  (1993/94)                  Supervising sound editor

16.Romeo is bleeding (1994)                                            Supervising sound editor

17.There Goes the Neighborhood (1992)                      Supervising sound editor

18.The Hand that Rocks the Cradle (1992)                   Supervising sound editor

19.Hard Promises (1991/92)                                             Supervising sound editor

20.A Rage in Harlem (1991)                                              Supervising sound editor

21.Defending your Life (1991)                                           Supervising sound editor

22.Bad Influence (1990)                                                      Supervising sound editor

23.Far from Home (1989)                                                   Supervising sound editor

24.Warlock (1989)                                                                Supervising sound editor

25.Rocket Gibraltar (1988)                                                 Supervising sound editor

26.Surf Nazi Must Die (1987)                                             Supervising sound editor

27.The Tomb (1986)                                                              Supervising sound editor

Comment: @ShaunKelly, I feel that the community here have been going along a different path, that of supporting and promoting sound design. I'm afraid this thread does not serve the topic that we're all enjoying around here, plus it looks like you're fishing for visitors to your personal site. Your operation feels slightly out of place to me.

Comment: I removed the link and posted the entire list here. I know its not a question but, I thought people here would want to check out these films since Dane Davis is one of the greatest sound designers around and they are easy to access instantly on Netflix. If more people think this posting is out of context will will be happy to remove it. 

Comment: @ShaunKelly, thanks for posting the list. I'm a big fan of Dane's work and was previously unaware of many of the films you've listed above. I'd like to know how many of them you have seen, and why is each one remarkable/unremarkable in relation to the sound design?

Comment: @Jay, I have watched Aeon Flux recently and talked with Dane about it. The scenes when the people travel to the mental space where the red head lady is, there is the coolest ambience/voice effect going on. Dane described it as a deconstruction of the ladies voice. Really cool effect you should defiantly check it out. It happens several times throughout the movie.Also listen for the birds in the movie, Dane described them as being an evolved sound of the birds today. I didn't notice when I first watched it but will watch again to see what he was talking about. The others I will watch soon.

Comment: @ShaunKelly, my apologies for being a little acid earlier; you were showing a snippet of your list, mentioning Netflix and sending us to your site and it looked like you were spamming a little... It deserves to be put in context, maybe you could explain shortly why you want us to know about these movies. @Jay's answer does contribute to that, I shall stand corrected.

Comment: I know what I'll be watching: Surf Nazi Must Die ... How about that for a title

Comment: A link to his IMDB would suffice...

Comment: I made the list because these are so easy to access and find specific spots in the films.You don't have to wait for it for 3 days in the mail or even drive to the local video store to rent. It makes it easier for someone trying to find stuff in the film. I have no correlation with Netflix. I just think it would be cool if we could watch these films and talk about what we find. So watch Aeon Flux and check out the cool vocal effect Dane did in the place with the red head lady.At 12min in to 15 min. Really cool effects.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a question, I think it's a good post and worth an up vote, since some folks may not be aware of Dane's work and he is one of the most influential and interesting sound designers of our generation, imho.

PS> Dane also supervised and designed for Treasure Planet -- a beautifully crafted track that really made the film special.

Comment: He also did the voice of Morph in treasure planet. 

Comment: yes, loved that character!